# GooglePlacesAutocomplete - passing info to parent component and defining language

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react sign-up form I have the GooglePlacesAutocomplete component to autocomplete user city and country. I have a question - how do I pass the selected city and country to my parent component's state? Normally I use onChange but it doesn't work. onPress doesn't work either (or I am using it incorrectly).

The code looks something like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import GooglePlacesAutocomplete from 'react-google-places-autocomplete';

export default class SignUp extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            cityAndCountry: ''
        };
   }
render() {
  return ( 
      <h2>Place of birth</h2>
      <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        apiKey="myApiKey"                    
        autocompletionRequest={{ types: ['(cities)'] }}
        apiOptions={{ language: 'en'}}                  
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this prop defined in their official docs.

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
   selectProps={{
     value,
     onChange: setValue,
   }}
 />
```

Comment: I've tried but I got the following error "'value' is not defined 'setValue' is not defined" What should I do?

Comment: finally managed to make it passing value to redux store